# How to define spaces between two lines using CSS?

Tags: css

Margin, padding, or whatever?

Comment: Jeez, surprised this question didn't get closed. So short. You're a lucky man!

Answer (score 22):

line-height attribute, more details: http://www.css3.com/css-line-height/

Comment: Note that even though that link points to css3.com, line-height has been in the spec since CSS1.

Comment: Yes, and it is supported by all browser. Also it is usually better to use em as unit for it, as some browser will not scale it with the text properly otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

Margin is used to specify the distance between elements.

Padding is used to specify the padding between an element and it's content.

Line-height is used to specify the height of text lines in a continuous text.

So, if you have separate elements that you want a distance between, margin is appropriate:

```
<p style="margin: 5px 0">Line 1</p>
<p style="margin: 5px 0">Line 2</p>
```

If you have a continuous text where you want a distance between the text lines, line-height is appropriate:

```
<p style="line-height: 1.8em">Long text that spans several lines...</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

If your lines stored in single `<div>` or `<p>` element, your can use(as was mentioned above) `line-height`([line-height](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_line-height.asp)) attribute.
In case, when lines are placed in different block elements, yuo can modify space between two lines with `margin`([margin description](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_margin.asp)) or `padding`([padding description](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)) attributes.